# Spring Data MongoDB Date Between

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, mongodb-java

I use spring data mongodb.

I want the records between two dates. The following MongoDB Query works:

```
db.posts.find({startDate: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

My attempted Spring data query object code translation does not work:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("startDate").gte(startDate)
                            .and("startDate").lt(endDate));
```

What is the correct order of method calls to build the Mongo query I need?

Comment: When you put filedName (eg. startDate) more than once you get **InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException** ....you can't add a second 'startDate'...

Comment: What is the type of __startDate__ and __endDate__?

Answer (score 115):

Do not include the '**and("startDate")**' part in your criteria.

Instead of :

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("startDate").gte(startDate).and("startDate").lt(endDate));
```

You should use:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("startDate").gte(startDate).lt(endDate));
```

When you include the 'and("startDate")' part, Mongo see's it as two different entries on the same property.

Comment: That is a completely correct answer and should be marked as correct.

Comment: just making a note here that "startDate" and "endDate" are java.util.Date objects and will produce a mongodb query like "startDate" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2014-09-01T07:00:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2014-10-01T07:00:00.000Z"}}}

Comment: query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("dob").gte(startDate).lt(endDate)); did not work in my case. What i should use to find dob object in db like :
"dob" : ISODate("1991-01-22T18:30:00Z"),

Comment: @java25 so how do you fix it

Answer (score 17):

You also can add query annotaion:

```
@Query("{'date' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 } }")                 
public List<AnyYourObj> getObjectByDate(Date from, Date to);
```

Or proper spring data method signature:

```
public List<AnyYourObj> findByDateBetween(Date from, Date to);
```

Both of these approaches give the same result.
You can read more here https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb
and here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: how to add where condition on specific field on top of it?  for example. i want AnyObject.company="flipkart" . It would be great if you can provide spring data signture for that

Comment: @Query ("{'date' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 }, 'company': ?2  }" and method  public List<AnyYourObj> findByDateBetweenAndCompany(Date from, Date to, String company);

Answer (score 12):

[Reference here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/due-to-limitations-of-the-basicdbobject-you-cant-add-a-second-and/)

```
Query query = new Query(
  Criteria.where("ip").is(ip)
  .andOperator(
    Criteria.where("createdDate").lt(endDate),
    Criteria.where("createdDate").gte(startDate)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 7):

I had to find dates between on field `publishedDate` and here is how I did it:

```
    Criteria publishedDateCriteria = Criteria
                        .where("publishedDateObject").gte(psDate)
                        .lte(peDate);
    Query query = new Query(publishedDateCriteria);
    mongoTemplate.find(query,
                        MyDocumentObject.class));
```

Comment: Thank you James, It really helpfull.

Comment: @user3327951, great to know. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I did like this

```
public interface PolicyRepository extends MongoRepository<Policy, String> {
    @Query("{'lastDate':{$gt:?0,$lt:?1}}")
        public List<Policy> findAllPolicies(Date today,Date somedate);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works on version 2.7.2 of the Java driver

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("posts");  

BasicDBObject date = new BasicDBObject();
date.append("$gte", new Date(startDate));
date.append("$lte", new Date(endDate));

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("date", date);

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

Also, for the record you have "startDate" for both the gte and the lte parameters.

Answer (score 4):

It works, he is some sample code:

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("pt").gte(startDate)
       .andOperator(Criteria.where("pt").lt(endDate));
```

Comment: I am trying something like to search for dob. But I could not find any user. Although their are 200 users in database. 
criteria = Criteria.where("dob").lt(startDate.getTime()).gte(endDate.getTime());

Answer (score 3):

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyObject, MyObjectId> {
    List<MyObject> findByMydatefieldBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries

Answer (score 3):

Use MongoRepository Query method like this:

```
List<T> findByStartDateBetween(Range<Integer> dataRange);
```

use Range for detail range settings.

[simliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848428/spring-data-mongodb-between-change-from-gt-lt-to-gte-lte/70001649#70001649)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (metaData.getToValue() == null){
dynamicCriteria = Criteria.where("metaData.key").is(metaData.getKey()).andOperator(Criteria.where("metaData.value").is(metaData.getFromValue()));
}else {
dynamicCriteria = Criteria.where("metaData.key").is(metaData.getKey()).orOperator(Criteria.where("metaData.value").gte(metaData.getFromValue()).lt(metaData.getToValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below query. This should work for your case.

```
Query query = new Query(
        Criteria.andOperator(
            Criteria.where("startDate").gte(startDate),
            Criteria.where("startDate").lt(endDate)
        )
    );
```

Comment: can you try to explain the answer that you attempted along with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this could be create a DateUtility class to get `LocalDateTime` from input `LocalDate`:

```java
public class DateUtility {
    public static LocalDateTime toStartOfDay(LocalDate date) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(date).map(LocalDate::atStartOfDay).orElse(null);
    }

    public static LocalDateTime toEndOfDay(LocalDate date) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(date).map((localDate) ->
                localDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX)).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Then use it in the query criteria:

```java
Query query = new Query();  query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("startDate").gt(CommonUtils.toStartOfDay(startDate)).lt(CommonUtils.toEndOfDay(startDate)));
```

This query will give result from whole day for a given date.

Answer (score -1):

[Search By Date Column in spring boot mongo db using criteria(Complex Query)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL6W2.png)[Search by date column in spring boot mongodb using criteria[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoWlv.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).