# How compare date in spring mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to fetch result bw two date in Mongo and spring but it show parse exception.

If I pass like date as string then no result. How compare date in spring and Mongo application.

```
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("date").gte(new Date("2018-06-24")).lte(new Date("2018-06-30")));
```

My collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b34a31a68f1b041aa13b82f"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-06-28T00:00:00Z"),
    "eventname" : "app open"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startDate = df.parse("2018-06-24");
Date endDate = df.parse("2018-06-30");
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("date").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));
```

Please see also [Spring Data MongoDB Date Between](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311061/3260495) and [Spring data mongodb search for ISO date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30273355/3260495) for further information.