# spring-data-mongodb : Between change from ($gt, $lt) to ($gte, $lte)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

In my repository I've added the following method :

```
List<Event> findByEventDateBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
```

Generated query by spring-data-mongo is :

> [debug] 2020-09-11 15:39:59,550 - o.s.d.m.c.MongoTemplate - find using
> query: { "eventDate" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : 1577833200000 }, "$lt" :
> { "$date" : 1599775200000 } } } fields: Document{{}} for class: class
> xxxxxx

Is there a way to tell spring data to use `$gte` and `$lte` instead of `$gt` and `$lt` when using **Between** keyword ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of **@Query** annotation as follows:

```
@Query(value = "{'eventDate':{ $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1}}")
List<Event> findByEventDateBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is simpler:

```
List<Event> findByEventDateBetween(Range<LocalDate> dateRange);
```

call:

```
findByEventDateBetween(Range.closed(start, end))
```

reference：

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

```
lower / upper bounds ($gt / $gte & $lt / $lte) according to Range
```